# Why modal shows withut calling it?

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal in HTML which I want to toggle after clicking on a button but I cant get it to work. Modal content appears in the main view and it doesn't toggle.

```
    <a href="#myModall" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModall" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body…</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

The code above is taken from [this](https://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals) tutorial where it actually works!

P.S. I dont want to reload HTML in order to toggle the modal due to some values I have and I will lose them.

EDIT:

```
<head>
<title>Add 

devices</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <?php if ($show_modal) : ?>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#myModal").modal('show');
                $('#modalTable').DataTable({
                    searching: true,
                    paging: true,
                    info: true
                });
            });
        </script>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("select.device_type_id").change(function() {
                var selectedType = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
                window.Var1 = selectedType;
                //  alert("You have selected the type id - " + selectedType);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "./createDevice.php",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: {
                        unit: selectedType
                    },
                    dataType: "text",
                    success: function(html) {
                        $('#confirmation').html(html);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

    <script>
        function pageRedirect() {
            if (window.Var1 == null || window.Var1 == 'Select') {
                alert("Your forgot to choose device type!");
            } else {
                window.location.href = "add_devices_ble.php";
            }
        }
    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <a href="#myModall" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="myModall" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>One fine body…</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Most likely you have conflicting css. Check if you are using .hide class elsewhere.

Comment: Share your entire HTML file.

Comment: Or check if you have triggered your model. Like $('#myModall').modal('show') .

Comment: @Devang check the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your sample page might not have loaded the necessary css and javascript files for bootstrap. Remember the bootstrap css files can get you most of they way, but once you start adding dropdown and navbars and modals, you need the javascript as well. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/ for the cdns to load.

Comment: which one I actually need because if I add the css link and all three scripts it works somehow but the modal doesn't look proper and I cant close it

Comment: I checked you link again and your tutorial has a warning that it's bootstrap 2 which is old. Why don't you try this example of a modal as it should work with the modern bootstrap 4: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/modal/

Comment: thanks , I am now. It works fine now but the buttons dont appear properly, their names are outside and they dont have a proper width

Comment: You might check the button examples on the bootstrap 4 and make sure your class names are up to date now that you've upgraded. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/buttons/